# How to make a circular density/contour plot with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I wish to show a plot in which each radius represent a colour. So I have set of radii and the density for each radius like this:

```
#radius #density
1     0.9
1.5   0.8
2     0.6
2.5   0.4
.... many more
```

I know how to plot one radius but how I can plot in some sort of circular(radial) density/contour like plot?

Comment: Can you show an example, how that should look like? For circles, you can use the `with circles` plotting style. For a data file with descending radius values, you could also draw filled, overlapping circles. Or do you want a 'real' density distribution, which interpolates the values etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possibility: Thats draws overlapping circles, which are coloured according to the current palette definition. For this to work, the data must be sorted with descending radius values, which is done here on-the-fly using the `sort` Unix command line tool:

```
set palette defined (0 'white', 1 'blue')
set cbrange [0:1]
unset key
plot '< sort -r data.dat' using (0):(0):1:2 with circles lc palette fillstyle solid noborder, \
     '' using (0):(0):1:($2+0.1) with circles lc palette lw 3
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Christoph, what is (0):(0) in (0):(0):1:2. If I remove this  (0):(0) then gnuplot complains "not enough colors". We can use () for some live function e.g. ($2+something) but dont know what (0):(0) performs here?

Comment: `(0)` just uses the number `0` as value, i.e. with `using (0):(0)...` all circles are drawn with the origin as their center.